# Prevent the same job to run twice node-cron

Tags: node.js, typescript, scheduled-tasks, chron

I'm working with node and typescript, using node-cron 2.0 to schedule a background operation to run every hour.

```
  cron.schedule("0 0 * * * *", () => {
     purgeResponsesSurveys();
   });
```

I'm concerned about what happens if the method doesn't finish within 1 hour since I don't want two instances of my method to run at the same time.

What are the best practices to prevent the scheduler from invoking the function `purgeResponsesSurveys` if it is already running from the previous hourly invocation?

Comment: Can you not store the state in a variable and simply check if you already called the function?

Comment: maybe... I'm not sure if it is safe from a concurrency standpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Semaphore`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) to prevent parallel calls.

You will need to know when `purgeResponsesSurveys` is done. So if it's asynchronous you will need to return `Promise` or receive a `callback` that will be called when `purgeResponsesSurveys` is done.

I used [semaphore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore) npm package.
Here is a small example/simulation.

```js
const semaphore = require('semaphore');

const sem = semaphore(1);

simulateCron(function() {
    console.log('cron was triggered')

    // wrap task with mutex
    sem.take(function() {
        longTask(function(){
            sem.leave();
        })
    })

})

function longTask(cb) {
    console.log("Start longTask")
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb()
        console.log("Done longTask")
    }, 3000)
}

function simulateCron(cb) {
    setInterval(cb, 500)
}
```

```
// output
cron was triggered
Start longTask
cron was triggered
cron was triggered
cron was triggered
cron was triggered
cron was triggered
Done longTask
Start longTask
cron was triggered
...
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I'm wondering how did you decide to use semaphore(1) over mutex?

Comment: `semaphore(1) == mutex` when using this lib. But as long as you have some kind of Lock set to 1 you will be OK.

Comment: Does it work also if the application is deployed in a cluster?

Comment: In principle, you should have only *one* instance of this application running. If you have many many tasks on one npm possess can't handle them I would suggest using Redis or Queue lib to delegate the semaphore to.